# Kernel modules: Configure gpio_chips for external GPIO pins

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, i2c, gpio, nvidia-jetson

I am working with FPD Link III. My set-up contains an nvidia platform, deserializer, a serializer and a camera. The camera has GPIO pins and I want to access them using fpd_link (which use i2c commands). Is it possible to configure a gpio_chip for the camera's gpio pins?
The problem is that those GPIO pins does not have valid numbers, addresses, ... They are accessed through the serializer registers.

Appreciate your help!

I have already instantiated the `gpio_chip` and had already defined the `get`,`set`,`input_direction` and `output_direction` functions but didn't how to map gpio lines of the gpio_chip and the external physical pins
I tried `gpio_desc` but did not work.

Comment: Yes, GPIO chip is a software abstraction, it doesn’t and shouldn’t know about beneath protocol, just put your proper code snippets in those callbacks and that’s it. The lines numbering starts from 0, you may number them as you wish, but better is to follow the data sheet.

Comment: I have implemented my proper code and I can access them now! Thank you for your help. I can get and set those GPIOs. Do you know how to modify the unused status?

Comment: That status shows which GPIOs are being used by kernel. If you have no driver using a GPIO, it won't be used.